# Print web page (HTML 5 canvas) without printer prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, printing

I'm able to print HTML5 Canvas content. But every time when I click print a window prompts to select printer and settings.

How to make silent printing? I need the browser to print in default printer without prompt.

I need the solution for IE 10 and later, Edge and Chrome.

Comment: Thankfully, you can't. Letting any web page to print anything they want without asking would be horrible.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work as granting the web page access to printing without a prompt would be a security problem.

There may however be an option (flag) for disabeling the printing dialog in your browser. But this would affect all websites viewed in this browser.

Comment: I agree. But I'm build application that works only in local network. There are few extensions available to suppress the popups. In my case I should not use extensions.

Comment: hm. Would a desktop application (written in HTML, CSS, JS) be an option for you? I'd guess, there you can do such things.

Comment: I'm sorry, but as far as I know, that's impossible from a pure JS persepective unless you can modify your browser via flags, plugins etc.

Answer (score 0):

From a web application you cannot access resources on local machine like file system or installed applications. If you need this capability in your web application, you need to develop some browser plugin which can do this job.